# Value changed while nested map in java

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I tried to create map (in) inside of the map (out). But, the value of "out" change after I change the "in". This is the example of my code:

```
      Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> out = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>();
      LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> in = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
      
      in.put("a", 100);
      out.put("u", in);
      System.out.println(out);
      out.put("s", in);
      in.put("b", 500);
      System.out.println(out);
```

This is the output:

```
{u={a=100}}
{u={a=100, b=500}, s={a=100, b=500}}
```

What should I do to get this result:

```
{u={a=100}}
{u={a=100}, s={a=100}}
```

Comment: the map is "out" and "in". "a" is a key that I used to fill the "in" map, sorry for my english

Comment: oh, I forgot to change the variables, here it is

Comment: i concerned about that too. but if I tried, for example:  a = Map<String, String>; String b = "test"; a.put("1", b); b = "tst"; a.put("2",b);    the result would be : {a="test", b="tst"} and not {a="tst", b="tst"} . Or my question is just happened for map?

Answer (score 2):

I only tried to guess what do you exactly want. But if you change inner object then outer object continue reference to the same instance. So, for example, you can create new objects while putting into outer link:

```
    Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> out = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> in = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    in.put("a", 100);
    out.put("u", new LinkedHashMap<>(in));
    System.out.println(out);
    out.put("s", new LinkedHashMap<>(in));
    in.put("b", 500);
    System.out.println(out);
    System.out.println(in);
```